# With the mongodb-java-api, is it possible to "select" the objectID and return the value from a Mongodb.find operation in one operation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am interested in to find the id from a single document as the result of a find operation.

In Robomongo I can get the value in question with this statement:

```
db.collection.find({ "field" : {$exists: true}}).limit(1).next()._id.valueOf()
```

What is the minimal code in Java I have to use to get the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to find only one document you can use

```
DBCollection.findOnefindOne(DBObject query, DBObject projection)
```

Also, you need to find only `_id`.  So, I projected only `_id`.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject obj =  collection.findOne(new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject(
            "$exists", true)),new BasicDBObject("_id",1));
    ObjectId id = (ObjectId) obj.get("_id");        
    System.out.println(id.toHexString());
```